# in jquery how to add prepend list item to ul retriving from input field

Tags: jquery

I want to add append to ul that is getting from input field I want to display like list items.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
if ($('input:text').val().length == 0)
{
alert("please enter the text");
}
else {
$('#demo').append(<li>('#myText').val()</li>);
}
});
});
</script>
<body> 
<input type="text" id="myText" onfocus="this.value=''">
<button>add</button>
 <ul id="demo">
 </ul>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `prepend` to solve this ref http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        if (!$('#myText').val().trim())
        {
            alert("please enter the text");
        }
        else
            $("#demo").prepend('<li>'+$('#myText').val()+'</li>')     
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body> 
    <input type="text" id="myText" onfocus="this.value=''">
    <button>add</button>
     <ul id="demo">
     </ul>
 </body>
```